# Android CustomView (extends from ImageView) fill with White

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

This Android App features a Signature Pad.

This is accomplished by a Custom View which extends from ImageView, and overriding the`onTouchEvent()` and `onDraw()` methods.

Now, if the user makes a mistake, we want to allow wiping the signature pad clean, and let the user start over. We are trying to accomplish this with an `fillWhite()` method.

**How can we fill the ImageView with white?**

```
public class SignatureView extends ImageView {
// setup initial color
private final int paintColor = Color.BLACK;
// defines paint and canvas
private Paint drawPaint = null;
// stores next circle
private Path path = new Path();

// set up default measurements of the signature pad
private final int PX_SIGNATURE_PAD_WIDTH = 521;
private final int PX_SIGNATURE_PAD_HEIGHT = 134;

private Canvas mCanvas = null;
public static Context stContext;
public static  AttributeSet stAttrs;

public int iScale = 0; // the scale factor from signature pad to Signature View


public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    stContext = context;
    stAttrs = attrs;
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (null == drawPaint)
    {
        // Setup paint with color and stroke styles
        // Do this only the first time, when null == drawPaint
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Log.w("SigView","Set strokewidth to: "+3*iScale+" pixels");
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(3 * iScale);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
    if (null == mCanvas) {
        mCanvas = canvas;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();
    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    // Force a view to draw again
    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
/*
Note that the below implementation does not work
*/

public void fillWhite() {
    setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
    // Force a view to draw again
    postInvalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    // test if we are allowed to change the size of the SignatureView:
    final int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    boolean bResizeWidth = widthSpecMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
    boolean bResizeHeight = heightSpecMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
    if (bResizeWidth && bResizeHeight)
    {
        // Yes, we ARE allowed to change the size of the SignatureView:
        Dimensions d = fitSignaturePadIntoView(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension( d.width, d.height );
    }
    else
    {
        // We are NOT allowed to change the size of the SignatureView:
        setMeasuredDimension( widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec );
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Call `reset()` on the `Path` and `invalidate()`.

Comment: @Mike M. Thanks you kindly, sir. `path.reset()` works. Please post as an answer so I can upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've set the `View`'s background color to white, you just need to empty the `Path` and cause a redraw.

```
path.reset();
invalidate();
```

I would also suggest moving the `Paint` object initialization to the constructor. Even though the `if` will skip it after the first draw, you're redrawing on every touch event, so it's best to keep the `onDraw()` method as tight as possible.

Comment: `Paint` object is in `onDraw()` because I need to `drawPaint.setStrokeWidth()` **after** I get the View's dimensions from `onMeasure()`

Comment: I kinda figured that's what you were doing, but I didn't see `iScale` anywhere in `onMeasure()`, and the `if` in `onDraw()` is effectively preventing any change to the `Paint` object there anyway. Just put the `setStrokeWidth()` call in `onMeasure()`, and move everything else to the constructor.

Comment: That makes sense. I will do that. Thanks.